# cherrypy mark a handler to be run as a daemon thread?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, cherrypy

I have the following cherrypy application:

```
class Hqyc:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        with open('index.html', 'r') as content_file:
            html_content = content_file.read()
        return html_content

    @cherrypy.expose
    def long_running(self):
        # do some long running computation in background
```

Now as it is, when I hit `Ctrl+C` to terminate the main thread, the app will wait for the child thread to stop, and it can take forever. How can I mark the `long_running` handler as running as a daemon thread, so immediately after the main thread stops, the whole application would stop?

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? Python does not have any thread cancellation APIs.

Comment: The problem is stated in my question, to terminate a long-running child thread when you exit the main thread from Cherrypy.

Comment: Wait, that's the desired solution but you're solving something else by running a thread in the first place, aren't you? Why do you need that thread?

Comment: @webKnjaZ, oh I understand. For example if you need a long-polling service thread.

Comment: Why would you need a thread for that? What would it do? CherryPy handlers already run in threads.

Comment: Do you really understand what 'long-polling' mean?

Comment: Yes, I know what it is. And it's not a long computation as the comment in your snippet suggests.

Comment: long-polling doesn't mean 'long' computation at all as you indicated. It means always in ready mode. Look if you don't understand the topic, why not just leave it alone? thx

Comment: I maintain CherryPy. I think I understand some things about it. And I'm trying to be helpful by figuring out the whole picture.